# multiple controller in one route

Tags: php, routes, phalcon

I have to use static routes same as :

```
$router->add("/v1/places/GetList",
["namespace"=>"v1","controller"=>"places","action"=>"GetList"]);

$router->add("/v1/places/getPlace",
["namespace"=>"v1","controller"=>"places","action"=>"GetPlace"]);
```

so our users should to type correctly URL and follow our policy to access controls : `/v1/places/GetPlace`

what I can to do that users can access to our app same as this url : `/v1/places/getplace`

Answer (score 0):

just use regex same as :

```
$router->add("/v1/places/{w:([getplace,G,P])+}",
```